# Allowing decimals in field

Tags: javascript, html, numbers, field, submit

When I try to add a decimal input in my field, ex: 12.54. It says the following text:
Please enter a valid value. The two nearest valid values are 12 and 13.

It won't let me type decimal inputs in my field
....

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without the code, but most likely, you need to add the `step` attribute. Try in this snippet and notice that the second input works

```html
<form>
<input type="number" min=1 max=10/>


<input type="number" step="0.01" />
<button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is the code.....

Comment: <form onSubmit="javascript:add()">
    a: <input type ="number" name="a" id="a"><br>
    b: <input type="number" name="b" id="b"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>

  <script>
    function add() {
      var m = document.getElementById("a").value;
      var n = document.getElementById("b").value;
      var sum = parseInt(m) + parseInt(n);
      document.write ("Sum="+sum);
    }
  </script>

Comment: What should I add?

Comment: you are missing the `step`

Comment: I tried your snippet but this is the reaction when i put 1.2 in a box

Comment: I tried your snippet but it reacts with the same problem.

Comment: ..ps: sry it took so long